# Order by two columns that changes sort order

Tags: sql, toad

I have a table that looks likes this

```
ID  Side    Name    
--  ---    -------
1   Left   Bravo
1   Right  Alpha
2   Left   Delta
2   Right  Charlie
3   Left   Fox
3   Right  Echo
```

I need the Table to looks like this where it sorts the ID column and the Side column but the Side column is sorted Right and then Left

```
ID  Side    Name    
--  ---    -------
 1   Right   Alpha
 1   Left    Bravo
 2   Right   Charlie
 2   Left    Delta
 3   Right   Echo
 3   Left    Fox
```

I have tried using `order by ID,Side DESC` & `ASC` but the query result does not change

Comment: You tagged this with both MySQL and SQL Server. Those are different systems. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: Weird, `ORDER BY ID, Side DESC` should work just fine, are you certain of this?

Comment: @Lamak I am. doing a 'order by Name' sorts the third column but somehow the Side column won't budge. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @EdCottrell -Fixed the incorrect tag

Comment: What datatype is the `Side` column?, which RDBMS are you actually using?

Comment: @Nik Now you don't have either tag, which is not any more helpful. Which system are you using?

Comment: Anyway, the `ORDER BY ID, Side DESC` works in **[MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41db05/1)**, **[SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9fcc/1)**, **[Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e691/2)** and **[Postgres](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab68c/2)**, so not sure what your problem actually is

Comment: I got the query working with `ORDER BY ID, Side DESC` by shifting around some code. I am trying to figure out why it didn't work the first time and will post the solution here. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess from your result set what you need, exactly.

```
 ORDER BY Name
```

will produce the result you want.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceb736/1/0

```
 ORDER BY ID ASC, Side DESC
```

should also do the same.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceb736/2/0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`  for the side column

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY id ASC,
CASE WHEN `side` ='Right' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f44c/2)

Comment: Even though this would work, the query op said was using should also work

Comment: @Lamak yup you got in comments so need to move with another approach

Comment: I understand that, I'm just saying that since it didn't work out for op, then maybe the problem is elsewhere. I don't know how his query wouldn't work but yours would

Comment: @Lamak i agree with you there may be